# Stop scanf from waiting input, with another thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I would like to "send a message" to scanf from a thread to the main program, I'm asking how to give to "scanf" function, or "cin" function, something to stop waiting.

You usually write something on the console and press "enter".
How Can I do the same from another thread?

Example:

```
int main()
{
   ///// Some code to make the thread work ecc
   std::cin >> mystring;
   std::cout << mystring; // It should be "Text into mystring";
}


// From the other thread running...
void mythread()
{
    std::string test = "Text into mystring";
    // Write test to scanf! How?
}
```

How can I achieve that??

Comment: Your question needs some clarification.  It doesn't make sense to say "send a message to `scanf`",  Also, you don't want to use `scanf` with a C++ `std::string` anyway.  I can't really determine what you are asking here.

Comment: @frasnian Edited. Let me know if it is clearer

Comment: The input for `std::cin` typically comes from the keyboard or another file, not from the program itself. Are you looking to just set `mystring` with the string from `mythread()`. If so you should use `std::async()` and get the value from the returned future with `get()`. Have `mythread()` return `mystring`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood you are tring to send information between threads. The official name is called **Interthread Communication**.

If you want to use scanf you should use **pipes** which is a communication tool between **Processes** not Threads

Here is a way you can communicate between threads. Reader threads represents your scanf thread. Writer thread represents  mythread.

The system is simple. You have a shared memory. When one thread tries to write it, it locks the memory(which is queue in example) and writes. When the other one tries to read it, it again locks the memory and reads it and then deletes(pops from queue) it. If the queue is empty the reader thread waits until someone writes something in it.

```
struct MessageQueue
{
    std::queue<std::string> msg_queue;
    pthread_mutex_t mu_queue;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
};

{
    // In a reader thread, far, far away...
    MessageQueue *mq = <a pointer to the same instance that the main thread has>;
    std::string msg = read_a_line_from_irc_or_whatever();
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mq->mu_queue);
    mq->msg_queue.push(msg);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mq->mu_queue);
    pthread_cond_signal(&mq->cond);
}

{
    // Main thread
    MessageQueue *mq = <a pointer to the same instance that the main thread has>;

    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mq->mu_queue);
        if(!mq->msg_queue.empty())
        {
            std::string s = mq->msg_queue.top();
            mq->msg_queue.pop();
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mq->mu_queue);
            handle_that_string(s);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&mq->cond, &mq->mu_queue)
        }
    }
```